# the form control name in form controls and in form value has difference

Tags: angular

I'm working in an angualr project with forms ,but on of the form control fields has a problem, the form control field name formerly was base, but I noticed that despite giving that a value, after submitting form, the form control value is undefined.
After checking the project and not get results, I decided to change the form control name(hoping to get results), so I changed the form control name form base to bace, but I came across something more strange... the form control name in controls is bace but in value is base(and still undefind)

```
initialForm() {
this.calculateForm = this.fb.group({
  employeeId: [''],
  childrenCount: ['', Validators.required],
  jobPercent: ['', Validators.required],
  additionHour: ['', Validators.required],
  contracts: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.group({
      bace: ['', Validators.required],
      actionDate: ['', Validators.required],
      expirationDate: ['']
    })
  ]),
}
)
```

}

[bace in controls (also in ts and html files)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1efo.png)[but "base" in form.value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsUe1.png)

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>salary</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="bace" required>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: how did you access the value of bace ?

Comment: this.calculateForm.value.contracts.bace- see pictures for more details

Comment: create stackblitz, with this component

Answer (score 0):

It seems very odd. Could you create a Stackblitz to test it?

Another thing I could suggest is to be sure you are not having an ASCII problem, so the text looks like a "c" in bace, but that character is not recognised (though I don't think this is the case).

Another test you can try is print in the template (or Component class) the value for both cases:

`this.calculateForm.get('contracts').controls['bace']`

and

`this.calculateForm.get('contracts').controls['base']`

and see if the "bace" case can give you some more hints

Comment: this.calculateForm.get('contracts').controls['bace'] returned undefined!

Comment: Ok, that confirms your screenshot and that the FormControl (bace) does not belong to the FormGroup controls.

Are you using special characters/ASCII? What is you try to rename the variable in something else, like "testField" and check if this belongs to the formGroup? If this is the case, then it has somethign to do with "c" and "s" characters in your property.